# Laravel Undefined property: LengthAwarePaginator::$id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when I try to pass variable as paginate data to view I get this error, I can't find any document about this problem

get data and pass to view :

```
public function index()
{
    return view('tickets')
        ->withData(\App\Tickets::paginate(50));
}
```

and my view:

```
<table class='table-style' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    @foreach ($data as $key=>$contents)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$contents->title}}</td>
            <td>{{$contents->description}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<div style='clear:both;margin-left:12px;'> {!! $data->links() !!}</div>
```

or

```
<div style='clear:both;margin-left:12px;'> {!! $data->render() !!}</div>
```

Paginate result:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#198 ▼
  #total: 7
  #lastPage: 2
  #items: Collection {#202 ▶}
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost/laravel/public/tickets"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Comment: Try to use `{!! $data->render() !!}` instead of `{!! $data->links() !!}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It didn't any change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div style='clear:both;margin-left:12px;'> {{ $data->links() }}</div>
```

If it doesn't work then change your function from this

```
public function index()
   {
return view('tickets')
    ->withData(\App\Tickets::paginate(50));
   }
```

To

```
public function index(){
    $tickets = DB::table('tickets')->paginate(50);
    return view('tickets', ['tickets' => $tickets]);
   }
```

And in your `tickets` view

```
<div style='clear:both;margin-left:12px;'> {{ $tickets->links() }}</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't any change

Comment: Did you try to return your results to see if there any problem ?

Comment: I didn't see "data" key try to get the data without Pagination is it correct ?

Comment: yes its correct `array:7 [▼
  0 => {#199 ▶}
  1 => {#191 ▶}
  2 => {#198 ▶}
  3 => {#202 ▶}
  4 => {#203 ▶}
  5 => {#204 ▶}
  6 => {#205 ▶}
]
`

Comment: I'm so sorry sir. problem was inside view, after removing Form tag it resolved